# MigLayout Column Based Alignment

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout, ui-design

I'm currently using MigLayout to try to accomplish a column based approach to swing. Essentially, I have different size components to layout on the screen with varying heights. Below is an image of what I have so far using MigLayout.

[Example Mock Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3645v.png)

As you can see, I've sorted the objects by their height. Each object is a JPanel. I'm making the assumption in building this model that the width of each component is statically defined. I would like the objects to not be defined as a grid, but as a set of columns where each component will be aligned with the component above it which will remove the padding between the components. I have been unsuccessful in finding a layout manager to accomplish this task. I believe MigLayout has the most customization to it which is how I got this far.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: *"Any suggestions.."* I suggest you (form &) ask a specific question. *"..would be very much appreciated!"* You're welcome. Another suggestion: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: Got it! Use a flowy and nogrid vs grid layout

Comment: *"Got it!"* Congrats. Glad you got it sorted. :) Now you might do one of two things: 1) Delete the question, or.. 2) Answer the question yourself (below), to help others later.